# Java: Input strings with keyboard class

Tags: java, input, keyboard, compiler-errors

I'm trying to input information in Java console application but I can't seem to run it.

This is how my Java file looks like:

---

```
public class Ovning1_3 
{

     public static void main(String args[])
     {

         String name;
         System.out.println("Enter your name");
         name = Keyboard.readString();
         System.out.println(name);      
    }

}
```

---

But I get the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
Keyboard cannot be resolved
at Ovning1_3.main(Ovning1_3.java:9)
```

---

I have a keyboard.class file in my source folder.
I'm using Eclipse with Ubuntu.

Comment: A Keyboard.class file should be in your bin folder. The source folder is for .java files.

Comment: I have it in the bin folder. (I also tried it in src folder without success so as of now I have it in both folders but noone of them work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Unresolved compilation problem:
```

means that the code could not be compiled.

You have to import Keyboard, something like

```
import uitl.Keyboard
```

When you use classes from a different package (not the same package of the current class), you have to import the class. If the class is also in the same package then you need not import.

Classes are generally grouped into [Packages](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/packages.html).
How do you know the package? Go to the first like of the class. This should be something like `package xyz` meaning that the current class in the `xyz` package. The class will be in a folder called `xyz` then (This is the rule for packages: when you want to have a class in a package, say `abc.xyz` then the class should have a package declaration - the first line of the code - to be package `abc.xyz` and the file should be present in a folder `xyz` which in then should be in a folder `abc`.

Comment: I tried, import util.Keybaord in the top of my java file but it didn't work.

Comment: @Michael The `util` was just an example. It should be replaced by the package. Try `import Keyboard;`. BTW From where did you get the keyboard class? For what purpose are you using it?

Comment: I got the Keyboard.class from my teacher. It works for my friends who's using Windows with Textpad. All they had to do was putting the Keyboard.class file in their folder.

Comment: Did you put the keyboard class in the same folder where the Ovning1_3 class is present? And can you try to refresh and rebuild the project in eclipse (which I assume you are using)? Right click on the project -> Refresh. Project menu -> Clean and Project Menu -> Build Project

Comment: Haha, oh my stupid piece of... That was really dumb of me, all I had to do was to refresh to project after putting the Keyboard.class file into the folder. Thanks a lot Nivas. Kudos.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
try{

BufferedReader buf=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Enter your Number :");
        String  number=buf.readLine();
        System.out.println("your Number is :"+number);


 }catch(IOException ex){}
```

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 BufferedReader cannot be resolved to a type
 BufferedReader cannot be resolved to a type
 InputStreamReader cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: you have to put this in a try/catch like try{//your code}catch(IOException e){} .I think you have missed basics

Answer (score 0):

1. Java is case sensitive. A class file `keyboard` will contain a class `keyboard` **not** `Keyboard`.
2. Do you have imported your class? Or are both classes in the same package?

Comment: I haven't imported my class, I just put it in the same folder. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you're still having this problem but import it like this at the top of your code.

```
import cs1.Keyboard;
```

Then it should work properly. For example:

```
import cs1.Keyboard;
public class NamePrinting
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        System.out.println ("Enter your name");
        String name = Keyboard.readString();
        System.out.println (name);  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **import java.util.Scanner;** for the first line and Use scanner codes instead of the "keyboard" you will get the same result with keyboard.
Try like below.

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
 public class Hello {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    String name;
    System.out.print("enter your name:");
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    name = input.nextLine();


  }

}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier just to tell him to write `import whatever.class.path.to.Keyboard;`?