# Im having trouble with 'keyboard' in my program

Tags: java

our assignment objective is to implement 3 students grades in two different classes (Student, grades) and find the average 
here is what i have so far,

```
  public class Program01
    {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

            Student bob, john, matt;
            Grades grades; 

            grades = new Grades();

            double bobgrade, johngrade, mattgrade;

            bob = new Student();
            john = new Student();
            matt = new Student();

            bob.setup();
            john.setup();
            matt.setup();

            bob.display();
            john.display();
            matt.display();

            bobgrade = bob.overallGrade();
            johngrade = john.overallGrade();
            mattgrade = matt.overallGrade();

            grades.average(bobgrade, johngrade, mattgrade);



    System.out.println("The overall grade for the class is: " +    grades.theSectionAverage);
            }






public class Student
{
    Grades grades; 
    String fullName, firstName, lastName, name;
    int studentProgramGrade, studentExamGrade;

    public void setup(){
    setName();
    setGrades();
    }

    public void setName()
    {

    System.out.print("Please, enter the student's name in the form of Doe, John or Smith, Jane:");
    fullName = Keyboard.readString();

    firstName = fullName.substring(fullName.indexOf(" ") + 1, fullName.length()); 
    lastName = fullName.substring(0, fullName.indexOf(","));


    name = firstName + " " + lastName;
    }

    public void setGrades()
    {
    studentExamGrade = grades.setupExam(name);
    studentProgramGrade = grades.setupProgram(name);
    } 

    public void display()
    {
    System.out.println(name + " " + grades.display());
    } 

    public double overallGrade()
    {
    final double PROGRAM_WEIGHT = 0.40;
    final double EXAM_WEIGHT = 1 - PROGRAM_WEIGHT;

    double theOverallGrade;

    theOverallGrade = studentProgramGrade * PROGRAM_WEIGHT + studentExamGrade * EXAM_WEIGHT;

    return theOverallGrade;
    }
}






    public class Grades {


    int programGrade, examGrade;
    double theSectionAverage;

    public int setupExam(String studentname)
    {
    System.out.print("Please, enter the exam grade for " + studentname + ":");
    examGrade = Keyboard.readInt();


    return examGrade;
    }

    public int setupProgram(String studentname)
    {
    System.out.print("Please, enter the program grade for " + studentname + ":");
    programGrade = Keyboard.readInt();

    return programGrade;
    }

    public String display()
    {
    return programGrade + " " + examGrade;
    }

    public double average(double bobgrade, double johngrade, double mattgrade)
    {
    theSectionAverage = bobgrade + johngrade + mattgrade / 3;

    return theSectionAverage;
    }
    }
```

whenever i try to run this, i keep getting this error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    Keyboard cannot be resolved

```
at Student.setName(Student.java:18)
at Student.setup(Student.java:10)
at Program01.main(Program01.java:19)
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Exactly as it says.. What is `Keyboard`?

Comment: If `Keyboard` is a Scanner which I suspect it is, you neither declare it nor initialize it.

Comment: @WilliamGaul I think it's an external class or something..

Comment: @MarounMaroun Oops yeah Scanner is `nextInt()` not `readInt()`...but still, should be declared.

Comment: It seems that you have not declared keyboard variable in your class

Comment: I've seen `Keyboard` used a few times in random code, but it's definitely not defined in standard API. If you were told to use `Keyboard`, you need to find the source or JAR containing the file, or, if you weren't told to use it, use something like `Scanner` instead.

Comment: your title is very much misleading !

Answer (score 1):

I think by `Keyboard` you want to use `Scanner` in your program.

include the following line in your file

`import java.util.Scanner;`

and create an instance of it.

`Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);`

Or you have some other API that has a class called `Keyboard` then import that file into your program.

**Note:** And by the way `Scanner` doesn't have a `readInt()` method, it has only `nextInt()`

> This error may happen when you use Eclipse as IDE and try to run code that doesn't even compile. Check your Problems view in Eclipse, and fix the compilation errors before executing the application.

Comment: thank you for the answer, but could you please explain as to where i should include 'import java.util.scanner;' in the file? im fairly new to java

Comment: at the top of the file just after `package` declaration if you have any.

Comment: @gvnvhri since all your classes are public you should define each class in its own file and in whatever class that uses the `Scanner` you have to include the `import java.util.Scanner`. the import statement should be the first line in your file (if you are not using packages)

Comment: Obviously, this was a RUNTIME exception, so compilation has succeeded! Its rather an issue with the classpath setup for execution.

Comment: @GyroGearless: if Eclipse is used to run code that doesn't compile, this exception maybe thrown.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing the import for the Keyboard utils. [Java: Input strings with keyboard class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7282747/java-input-strings-with-keyboard-class)

Try importing it, should do the trick.

P.S: This has already been discussed in another topic.

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
 Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
```

instead of Keyboards