# i dont know whats wrong with my program,

Tags: java

im fairly new to java and this is my first programming assignment, our objective is to implement 3 students grades in two different classes (Student, grades) and find the average.
    we are to implement the following methods in the student and grade classes:
  Student class:

```
public class Student - Defines a student with a full name and a complete set of grades:

public void setup() - Sets all attributes of the student (name and grades).
private void setName() - Sets the name of the student.
private void setGrades() - Sets all the grades for the student.
public void display() - Displays the complete information on the student.
public double overallGrade() - Returns the overall grade of the student.

Grades class:
public class Grades - Defines a complete set of grades received by a student.

public void setup() - Sets the complete set of grades
public void display() - Displays the complete set of grades
public double average() - Returns the average of the complete set of grades (i.e., it returns a number between 0.0 and 100.0).
```

Here is my program:

```
public class Program01 {

public static void main(String[] args)
{
Student bob, john, matt;
Grades grades; 

grades = new Grades();

double bobgrade, johngrade, mattgrade;

bob = new Student();
john = new Student();
matt = new Student();

bob.setup();
john.setup();
matt.setup();

bob.display();
john.display();
matt.display();

bobgrade = bob.overallGrade();
johngrade = john.overallGrade();
mattgrade = matt.overallGrade();

grades.average(bobgrade, johngrade, mattgrade);

System.out.println("The overall grade for the class is: " + grades.theSectionAverage);
}
}



public class Student {
Grades grades; 
String fullName, firstName, lastName, name;
int studentProgramGrade, studentExamGrade;

public void setup(){
setName();
setGrades();
}

public void setName()
{

System.out.print("Please, enter the student's name in the form of Doe, John or Smith, Jane:");
fullName = Keyboard.readString();

firstName = fullName.substring(fullName.indexOf(" ") + 1, fullName.length()); 
lastName = fullName.substring(0, fullName.indexOf(","));


name = firstName + " " + lastName;
}

public void setGrades()
{
studentExamGrade = grades.setupExam(name);
studentProgramGrade = grades.setupProgram(name);
} 

public void display()
{
System.out.println(name + " " + grades.display());
} 

public double overallGrade()
{
final double PROGRAM_WEIGHT = 0.40;
final double EXAM_WEIGHT = 1 - PROGRAM_WEIGHT;

double theOverallGrade;

theOverallGrade = studentProgramGrade * PROGRAM_WEIGHT + studentExamGrade * EXAM_WEIGHT;

return theOverallGrade;
}

}




public class Grades {
int programGrade, examGrade;
double theSectionAverage;

public int setupExam(String studentname)
{
System.out.print("Please, enter the exam grade for " + studentname + ":");
examGrade = Keyboard.readInt();

return examGrade;
}

public int setupProgram(String studentname)
{
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Please, enter the program grade for " + studentname + ":");
programGrade = Keyboard.readInt();

return programGrade;
}

public String display()
{
return programGrade + " " + examGrade;
}

public double average(double bobgrade, double johngrade, double mattgrade)
{
theSectionAverage = bobgrade + johngrade + mattgrade / 3;

return theSectionAverage;
}
}
```

when i run my program=, it gives me the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
Keyboard cannot be resolved

at Student.setName(Student.java:16)
at Student.setup(Student.java:8)
at Program01.main(Program01.java:17)
```

any help would be greatly appreciated, like i said, im new to java.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Im having trouble with 'keyboard' in my program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19022199/im-having-trouble-with-keyboard-in-my-program)

Answer (score 2):

I think that's because you didn't import the Keyboard class, and you can get things about import from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html)

Answer (score 2):

You have a number of compilation errors in this program.  If you attempt to run a program that has compilation errors (in Eclipse's for example), you will get an exception

One the compilation errors is here:

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
...
programGrade = Keyboard.readInt();
```

In Java, identifiers are case sensitive, so `keyboard` and `Keyboard` are NOT the same identifier.

In another case, I noticed that you had attempted to use `Keyboard` at a point where wasn't even a declaration.

---

Stepping back from the compilation errors, a better way to deal with your input is to create the `Scanner` object *once* in `main` and then pass it to the methods of your domain classes (as required) as a method parameter.  If you can't pass it as a method parameter (because the method signature doesn't allow it), you could pass it as a constructor parameter or (puke<sup>1</sup>) declare a `public static` variable in the main class.

<sup>1 - You will (or should) be taught that using a `static` variable like that is bad practice, but you are currently at a stage in your learning where the explanation probably would not make sense to you.</sup>

---

But the main lesson is that you should correct ALL compilation errors before you try to run your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error:
    Unresolved compilation problem: Keyboard cannot be resolved
at Student.setName(Student.java:16)
at Student.setup(Student.java:8)
at Program01.main(Program01.java:17)
```

In Student.java, line 16, the word Keyboard is used, but is unknown ("not resolved").
Mostly this happens when an `import` is missing, or a typo occurred.

Tip: sometimes no line numbers are shown in the IDE, then look for settings to display them.

Also IDEs will allow auto-completion: typing "Ke" and then pressing Ctrl-Space to select.

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to java learn to understand the stack trace. Will help you a lot in long run. In your case

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
Keyboard cannot be resolved

at Student.setName(Student.java:16)
at Student.setup(Student.java:8)
at Program01.main(Program01.java:17)
```

It says exception occured in function setName() of class Student and the corresponding line number is 16. Now you must see this line to check what actually cause the exception.

Just for the record stacktrace will give you the exception propagation tree till it is either catched or if not catched finaly propagating to main leding to JVM shutdown. So in your case exception occured in method setName() of Class Student which was called in the method setup() of same class at line no. 8... and so on.

Now if you see line no. 16 of Class student which will be in the setName() methdod it is(most probably)

```
fullName = Keyboard.readString();
```

Here it does not recognize `Keyboard`. Going by the java naming convention it seems like a Class. If it is a class then you must import it and then you can call it's static function readString(). If it is variable (first change the name to camel case) then instantiate the object forst and then call the method on it.